# Is any way to conversion the type of instance

Tags: c#, types

I have two classes as below, one inherit from another. Nothing need to implement for this case.

```
Class super
{
    //nothing
} 
Class sub:super
{
    //nothing
}
```

Now I create a instance as below statement

```
sub actualSub=new sub();
```

So, we have a instance actualSub. Which type object pointer is type sub and actual type is sub.

Consider their inherit relationship,Is there any way to convert actualSub's actual type to super?
In other words, how could I make actualSub.GetType() return type super? 
Language is CSharp.

Comment: Why would you like to do that in the first place?

Comment: @gargankit WCF can't serilize Sub and I also can't add a [KnownType(typeof(Sub))] property below Super [Datacontract] as Sub class in fact shouldn't be known by Client.So I think the only way is conversion Sub type To Super Type.

Comment: For that you have to create instance of `super` not `sub`. It is not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible - `GetType` returns actual type of the object and there is no way to alter that behavior.

You can consider making copy if base class have some sort of copy constructor...

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, In fact I create a sub instance and want to pass it through WCF.

Answer (score 0):

```
actualB.GetType().BaseType.Dump();
```